# No podspec found for `geolocator_web` in `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_web/ios` flutter ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am pod installing.
This type error showing.

[!] No podspec found for `geolocator_web` in `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator_web/ios`

I am not uses of geolocator_web or geolocator.

flutter ios pod installing error showing.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If any of you are struggling with this error and none of the following methods works:

- `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get`
- `(arch -x86_64) pod repo update` & `(arch -x86_64) pod install`
- `Clean Build Folder` in XCode
- Delete project folder and clone git repo again
- Restart IDE
- Delete ios folder & `flutter create ios`
- ...

try this:

1. delete /.pub-cache in Flutter SDK folder
2. `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get`
3. `pod install`

I was always getting this "no podspec found for xxx~~" error where xxx can be any plugin, and figured out that some plugins never get their podspec file copied into  ios/.symlinks/pluginx/xxx/ios folder right after `pod install`.

After deleting /.pub-cache, I could confirm that all podspec files were in place.

`flutter pub cache repair` command seems like it does the same thing, but I didn't try this.

Comment: I am getting "no podspec found for xxx~~" and flutter pub cache repair works for me! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it worked by `flutter pub cache repair`. If I couldn't solve this, I had to delete my iOS(working app in appstore) folder. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For me I solved this by doing these steps:

## 1. I reverted my podfile to:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
     end
  end
end
```

## 2. and then do this on the terminal:

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
```

## 3. then:

```
flutter pub get
pod install
```

It's usually the podfile that causes these kinds of error

Answer (score 0):

I deleted ios folder
created again with `flutter create --platforms ios .`
Then ran `flutter pub cache repair` and it saved my day from all these errors